# iOS: how to add scrollable text view to application preferences?

Tags: ios, uitextview, application-settings

I need to add scrollable text view to my application preferences, like Apple's own legal page (look at Settings->General->About->Legal). How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround which does the job. Split long text you need to display into a set or paragraphs, each no longer than 500 bytes (I'm not sure about exact number, but if Title text in PSGroupSpecifier is too long, iOS won't display anything). Then create Legal.plist with separate PSGroupSpecifier element for each paragraph:

```
<dict>
<key>DoNotLocalize</key>
<string>YES</string>
<key>Title</key>
<string>Paragraph of boring text blah blah blah</string>
<key>Type</key>
<string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
</dict>
```

and then show it as a child pane. Bingo - you have a text scroller!

Answer (score 1):

Use a PSGroupSpecifier, setting the text you need as Title.
Observe that there is a limit to the amount of text you can have so you would need to use multiple group specifiers.
(as far as I can see, the limit is in the region of 500 chars per group)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>StringsTable</key>
  <string>Tos</string>
  <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>Type</key>
      <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
      <key>Title</key>
      <string>long, localizable, text!</string>
    </dict>   
  </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is using [`UITextView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html):

> The UITextView class implements the behavior for a scrollable, multiline text region. The class supports the display of text using a custom font, color, and alignment and also supports text editing. You typically use a text view to display multiple lines of text, such as when displaying the body of a large text document.

If you want to display a rich text, you can do that by loading your own HTML (stored as a resource file) into a [`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I know about UITextView. How do I add to application preferences? According to this spec:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Introduction/Introduction.html

I can only have switch, slider, text input, title, multivalue, group.